# Firefox 18 wierd canvas background behaviour

Tags: html, css, firefox, canvas

The following worked until I upgraded to Firefox 18, now it is changing most of the page so that it has a black background.    If I remove the border-radius, the overflow:hidden, or the background on button_body it seems to fix the issue.

Resizing the browser also seems to gives random results and if I make the window small enough it is making the window background and the browser background itself transparent so I can see through to the desktop.

Is there something I am doing wrong, or that I can change to still keep all my CSS styling but eliminate this problem?

```
<html>
<style>
    body, div, p, canvas {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #Main2 {
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        width:500px;
        height:300px;
    }
    #pDiv div.button_body {
        background: #396B9E;
    }
    #pDiv{
        position:absolute; 
        left: 100px; 
        top: 20px; 
        width: 136px; 
        height: 16px; 
        border-radius: 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;
        z-index:10;
    }             
</style>
<body>
<canvas  id="Main2">Upgrade your Browser!</canvas>
<div id="pDiv">
    <div class="button_body">
        test
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
        var _o = document.getElementById('Main2').getContext('2d');
        _o.fillStyle = 'rgba(208, 208, 208, 1)';
        _o.fillRect (0, 8, 200, 200);      
</script>
```

Here is an example page.
http://crystalvalleycomputers.com/test/test.html

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with canvas fillStyle.

Corrected Code:

```
 _o.fillStyle = 'rgba(208, 208, 208, 1)';
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  I missed that typo when entering it here.  But I don't see that fixing anything besides making the canvas gray, the rest of the page is still black and resizing the window still has an affect on the rest of the background.

Comment: check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NyBWc/ .I am also using firefox18.0.1,but its not showing what you said.

Comment: Yeah, for whatever reason it won't happen on a jsfiddle, maybe the iframe keeps it from happening?  However, if you view the output in its own window then it will.  http://fiddle.jshell.net/NyBWc/show/